# Problem with exponential formula

Tags: equations

I have a problem with this exponential formula. I don't know why the two 2s at the exponent are placed in different heights. And also the parenthesis have different size.

```
\begin{equation}
    PDF(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[ \left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sigma_x}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-y_0}{\sigma_y}\right)^2 \right]}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

How can I have the two terms written with the same dimensions?

Comment: $\sigma_y$ is slightly larger (depth) than $\sigma_x$, enough to bump a larger set of parenthesis.  By using $\big($ etc. you can avoid such inconsistencies.  Or use \vphantom.  Also, this would look better using $\exp$ instead of $e^$.

Comment: You can type `{}` or, maybe better, `\strut` directly before `^2` in both places to make them equally high.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @John Kormylo suggested in a comment above, this is caued by the `y` in `\sigma_y` extending lower than the `x` in `\sigma_x`. You can use `\vphantom` to handle this -- I usually do it this way --, though I'll admit it can get tedious in more complicated expressions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        \mathit{PDF}(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_x\sigma_y} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left[ \left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sigma_{x\vphantom{y}}}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{y-y_0}{\sigma_y}\right)^2 \right]}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

I've also used `\mathit{PDF}` here instead of just `PDF`; this'll give better spacing.